# Difference between IText-Jars and sources concerning pdf/a

Tags: jar, pdf-generation, itext, pdfa

I tried the example `part4.chapter13.PdfXPdfA` (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=226) by using the latest iText-Jras 5.4.1. The example did not work.

This error occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pdfIsoConformance
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.<init>(PdfAWriter.java:178)
...
```

Then I tried the pure java sources and the error vanished away.
I think the build of the jar file is wrong.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3):

You need two jars to make this example work:

- itextpdf-5.4.1.jar
- itext-pdfa-5.4.1.jar

Both jars are present in the ZIP that can be downloaded from SourceForge. I'm the one who made the release yesterday. With every release I test the examples. Note that the PDFs on itextpdf.com are already built with the SNAPSHOT for iText 5.4.2 (because we've already submitted new code today).